# Keep a DIV always visible

Tags: javascript, html

I have 7 section and one DIV inside each of the sections. I want one to be always visible, but when clicking the menu replace the previous one with the new DIV, but never hide all the DIVs, one must always be active.

I have this script but the DIV is only visible after clicking the menu:

```
$(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this).data('element');
    $("section > div:not("+el+"):visible").hide();
    $(el).show();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(e.currentTarget).data('element');
    $(el).show();
    $("section > div").not(el).hide();

  });
```

Explanation:

`$("section > div")` selects first level `div` under every `section` and `.not(el)` removes any element with a matching selector or object from the list/group and `.hide()` hides all elements left in the list.

Comment: When clicking on the button where I make the query the div still does not open and when I make a new query the div closes again, it remains the same as the function that I put in the question

Comment: What does your html look like?